# Hosting Laravel 5 project on my windows machine

Tags: php, laravel-5, server, web-deployment

I would like to host my laravel app on my Windows 10 machine so it can be visit through internet by IP address. Right now I'm developing using Homestead virtual machine.

Is there a way do make my app accessible through internet? If not, is a 000webhost.com a good choice to host my website? Is there another laravel friendly and free hosting service? I would pay for it if I know I will use it but right now I'm still experimenting.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, get a VPS. Depending on the size of your project you can get away with $10/mo or even cheaper.

It's a little more involved than getting a webhost package, but with the extra work comes more control.

Check out www.ovh.ie or www.digitalocean.com

If you don't want a VPS, you need to find a provider that allows you to change your project root. A lot of webhost providers has a root folder, and that's it. Laravel uses root/public. If your webhost won't let you set that as the public root, then you have to customize laravel and that's another annoyance as well.

Comment: In my opinion any web host that doesn't let you change something as simple as your public folder isn't worth dealing with.

Comment: @jfadich that's true. But some times prices can affect your decision. Some times you are even stuck with a clients host provider and then you are forced to make it work your applications side.